Typescript 'any' type error with dynamic array key
I'm getting the following error when trying to use a dynamic value for an array key.
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '`faults_${string}`' can't be used to index type 'HeatsTable'.

export interface HeatsTable {
    heat_id: UUID
    start: number
    faults_1: string[]
    faults_2: string[]
    faults_3: string[]
    faults_4: string[]
  }

const fault = heatData[`faults_${runningId}`]; // Throws the above TS error

Using keyof HeatsTable works but causes an error on another page because it thinks faults could be a number. Is there another solution for this that I'm missing?

Please [edit] to be a [mre] where heatData and runningId are declared (and where you don't use UUID without declaring it). Presumably you have runningId as type number; why not 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 as shown here? Then the problem goes away because TS knows that the key exists in HeatsTable. Does that meet your needs? If so I could write an answer; if not, please make sure your [edit] clarifies why not.

You could type runningId either manually or with extracting it from the type:
Playground
export interface HeatsTable {
    heat_id: string
    start: number
    faults_1: string[]
    faults_2: string[]
    faults_3: string[]
    faults_4: string[]
  }

declare const heatData: HeatsTable;
declare const runningId: number;

type RunningId = keyof {[K in keyof HeatsTable as K extends `faults_${infer A extends number}` ? A : never]: any}

const fault = heatData[`faults_${runningId as 1|2|3|4}`];
const fault2 = heatData[`faults_${runningId as RunningId }`];

